# css align header and textarea when there is border on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I'm trying to align the textbox and header. They are under the div container. If I set the width of the header and that of the textbox to be 100%, they can align. However, when I add the border (width:10px) to the textbox, I don't know how to align them. I tried to set textbox width to be 99%, but it doesn't always align well. I don't want to use only px for all width.

I wonder how to handle the problem? Thanks for any suggestion!

```
<div class="panel" style="float:left;">
    <div class="Header" style="width:100%">
        <p class="h">header name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ContentTB1">
        <asp:TextBox ID="text1" cssclass="txt1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea {
    height: 150px;
    border: 10px  solid #e6e6fa;
    width: 99%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

textarea:focus {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need it to work on older browsers you can try to use `calc` in your width, or maybe use a `box-sizing`.

Try one of these:

`width:calc(100% - 20px)` the border uses 20px (10 left and 10 right)

or

`box-sizing:border-box;` it will ignore your border or padding size and will keep the parent size.